# website multilanguage coding css not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

This code doess not work properly on the website im working on and I can't find out why. I'm trying to implement the menu, that's why I specified the menu items, but they are ignored and the 1 and 3 languages take the first and last 8, the 2 language takes the first 16 menu items out of a total of 24. Where is my problem?

```css
.first-lang .wsite-menu-default li:nth-child(-n+8){
    display: none!important;
}

.second-lang .wsite-menu-default li:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+16){
    display: none!important;
}

.third-lang .wsite-menu-default li:nth-child(n+17){
    display: none!important;
}
/* flag properties as shown in demo */

a.flaggy{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* properties for editor */

#icontent .flaggy{
    display: none
}

#icontent .wsite-menu-default li:nth-child(even){
    display: inline-block!important;
}

#icontent .wsite-menu-default li:nth-child(odd){
    display:  inline-block!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some `html`?

Comment: Which html file exactly? sorry for the noob question

Comment: Well just from staring at the CSS I don't see anything wrong - so it would help if you added the html that this applies to.